# Расположение картинок 3х3

Tags: css3, html5, изображения, hover

И так. Я только начал изучать всё это и не дали дз. Я немного не могу понять как это сделать. В общем мне нужно разместить таким образом фотографии. как это сделать верно я не знаю. Пытался через nth-child(), но всё не то. Пытался отдельно каждую картинку выставлять, но понимаю, что это бред сумасшедшого. Так же я хочу понять как сделать это черную область(Lorem ipsum), которая выезжает при наведении на картинку. Хотел бы увидеть ответы на эти два вопроса. спасибо за внимание и заранее спасибо за ответ. Фото прилагается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Курсор на ведён]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
[data-tooltip] {
width:200px;
height:200px;

background:#eee;
}
[data-tooltip]:before {
content: attr(data-tooltip);
display:block;
max-height:0;
overflow:hidden;
transition:10s max-height;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
max-height:100rem;


}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли

Comment: Если я вам помог пометьте ответ как правильный (галочка слева)

Comment: Простите, на сервисе впервые. Поставил

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так сделать:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
}

.photo-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-gap: 2em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.photo:nth-child(4n+1) {
  transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
}

.photo:nth-child(2n+2) {
  transform: rotate(2.5deg);
}

.photo {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s;
}

.photo::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.photo-sign {
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.photo-desc {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.photo:hover {
  transform: scale(1.125) perspective(20px);
  filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
  z-index: 1;
}

.photo:hover .photo-desc {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-gallery">
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно также сделать так, чтобы расстояние между изображениями зависело от размера экрана:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
}

.photo-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-gap: 2em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.photo:nth-child(4n+1) {
  transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
}

.photo:nth-child(2n+2) {
  transform: rotate(2.5deg);
}

.photo {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s;
  max-width: 170px;
}

.photo::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.photo-sign {
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.photo-desc {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.photo:hover {
  transform: scale(1.125) perspective(20px);
  filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
  z-index: 1;
}

.photo:hover .photo-desc {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-gallery">
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <span class="photo-desc">Lorem impsum dolor sir amet</span>
    <img class="photo-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCNY.png">
    <span class="photo-sign">Подпись</span>
  </div>
</div>
```